# Xcode Debugger Swift: Not able to view variables in debugger

Tags: xcode, swift

I am having troubles viewing the `self` variable details using XCode in swift. Would you guys know the solution to solve this issue? Thanks!

[image]

EDIT: 
I am running in debug mode.
I have noticed I made a variable with an empty string and that is displaying correctly.

[image]

Full Screenshot:
[image]

Under my swift compiler, the optimization level for debug is set to None.

Comment: Are you running in release mode?  You may have changed schemes or set your default scheme to run in release mode.  In the main menu: *Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme...*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not running the application in release mode.

Comment: Can you provide a complete screenshot of the Xcode window including the stack trace panel on the left?

Comment: Okay, I have provided the screenshot.

Comment: I'm still looking around for another issue that might cause this, but in case you haven't done so already, try cleaning, deleting derived data and restarting Xcode.

Comment: I have actually already tried that also.

Thanks man I appreciate it.